# @Output() with EventEmitter is working for <router-outlet> siblings?

Tags: angular, angular6

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet>
<app-header (cartRefresh)="pullCartItems(user_id)"></app-header>
<app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
</router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**header.components.ts**

```
pullCartItems(user_id) {
    console.log('Pull reached', user_id);
}
```

**events.components.ts**

```
@Output() cartRefresh: EventEmitter<any> =  new EventEmitter<any>();

addToCart(slug) {
  this.cart['event'] = slug;
  this.product.eventCart(this.cart).subscribe(response => {
    if (response['status'] === 1) {
      this.cartRefresh.emit(this.user_id);        
    } 
  });
}
```

**events.components.html**

```
<input type="button" value="ADD TO CART" (click)="addToCart(event.slug);" />
```

pullCartItems() not working on EventEmitter. Showing no error.
@output properties does not work with router outlet with siblings in angular6.
Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Use service with observable for communication. @output () don't' work on router-outlet

Comment: @Amitkumar .. Thank you for reply.
How to trigger header component method or update values from event component using service. Im new to angular.. Can you help me please...

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

https://github.com/paritosh64ce/ngx-pub-sub

What you need is a service with behaviorSubject/Observable for event communication. The above package is a wrapper of the same and offers other flexibility as well.